# Error Notice: Array to string conversion en PHP PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Alguien me podría ayudar y decir el por qué me manda ese mensaje?.

**Anexo el código:**

```
<?php

try{
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=organizer', 'root', ''); } catch(PDOexception $e){
    echo 'Error ' . $e->getMessage(); }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos-inicio.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TASKS | Reportes no tan importantes</title>

</head>
<body>
    <?php require('views/header.php'); ?>

        <div class="contenedor">    
            <div class="post">
                <p class="titulo">REPORTES NO TAN IMPORTANTES</p>
                <br>
                <hr>
                <article>
                    <?php 
                       foreach($reportes = $conexion->query('SELECT descripcion FROM tareas WHERE categoria = "No tan importante"') as $reporte){ // ESTA LINEA ES LA DEL ERROR!!!!!
                            echo '<li>' . $reporte . '</li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </article>
            </div>  
        </div>

    <?php require('views/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: la logica es confusa, pero estas convirtiendo un array en algo que se espera como string. No deberias leer antes el query, y despues hacer el foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es bastante sencillo , al  utilizar [$pdo->query()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php) directamente , obtendrá los datos con el estilo *fetch_style*  `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` es decir es posible acceder mediante indice numérico e indice del nombre de la columna en el `select` . Por lo tanto su variable $reporte es de tipo `array` y no es posible concatenar lo directamente.

```
echo '<li>' . $reporte[0] . '</li>';  //Esta opción
echo '<li>' . $reporte['descripcion] . '</li>'; //Otra opción
```

La solución puede ser la anterior o especificar el estilo de obtener los datos, para su caso con `FETCH_COLUMN` sería suficiente , es decir

```
foreach($reportes = $conn->query('SELECT descripcion FROM sexo WHERE descripcion = "m" ')
                         ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $reporte)
```

Pero se ve muy confuso y poco legible el código tal cuál está , deberías obtener los datos  antes de entrar al `foreach` , *(ejemplo)*

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=organizer', 'root', ''); 
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$data = $conn->query('SELECT descripcion FROM tareas WHERE categoria = "No tan importante" ')
            ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
foreach($data as $reporte){ 
    echo '<li>' . $reporte . '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente debes llamas en el foreach el elemento del array por su índice respectivo:

```
echo '<li>' . $reporte['descripcion'] . '</li>';
```